# How to avoid a continuous loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I've got a script which is suppose to work, but somehow it keeps running and running and running without processing a result.

thats the script

```
#working directory#
setwd("C:\\Users")

#data-files#
data = list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names= TRUE)
Y = length(data)

#Output#
output= data.frame(V1=NA, V2=NA, V3=NA, V4=NA, V5=NA, V6=NA, V7=NA, V8=NA, V9=NA, V10=NA)

for (i in 1:Y) {

A <- read.csv(file=data[i], header=TRUE, sep=";")

Duration = as.character (A[8,1])
Duration = as.numeric(strsplit(Duration," ") [[1]][4])
Timesteps = as.character((A[(13+Duration),1]))
Timesteps = as.numeric(strsplit(Timesteps," ") [[1]][2])

V1 = as.numeric(which(A==63569))
V1 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V1+1):(V1+Timesteps),1])))

V2 = as.numeric(which(A==41510))
V2 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V2+1):(V2+Timesteps),1])))

V3 = as.numeric(which(A==12885))
V3 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V3+1):(V3+Timesteps),1])))

V4 = as.numeric(which(A==43954))
V4 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V4+1):(V4+Timesteps),1])))

V5 = as.numeric(which(A==44422))
V5 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V5+1):(V5+Timesteps),1])))

V6 = as.numeric(which(A==42137))
V6 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V6+1):(V6+Timesteps),1])))

V7 = as.numeric(which(A==28667))
V7 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V7+1):(V7+Timesteps),1])))

V8 = as.numeric(which(A==63570))
V8 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V8+1):(V8+Timesteps),1])))

V9 = as.numeric(which(A==44525))
V9 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V9+1):(V9+Timesteps),1])))

V10 = as.numeric(which(A==43192))
V10 = as.numeric(max(as.character(A[(V10+1):(V10+Timesteps),1])))

#OUTPUT-FILES#
output [i,1] <- V1
output [i,2] <- V2
output [i,3] <- V3
output [i,4] <- V4
output [i,5] <- V5
output [i,6] <- V6
output [i,7] <- V7
output [i,8] <- V8
output [i,9] <- V9
output [i,10] <- V10

}

#result#
setwd("C:\\Users")
write.table(output,file= "XY.csv", sep= ";", dec=".", row.names=FALSE)
```

Maybe the way I set it up is to intricated or I missed a fairly simple part. I can't help myself right now.

Hints are highly appreciated!

Cheers,
Olli

Comment: How many files?  How big are each of the files?  There is nothing immediately obvious that would cause an infinite loop.  I would recommend adding some kind of `print()` or `write()` function within the for loop so that you can get a sense of how far along the task is.

Comment: hi @ErikKornet roughly 900 files each file about 300 KB and 3MB.

where would you include the `print()` and `write()` ?

150 files works fine but the total set causes an infinite loop

Comment: Right after `output [i,10] <- V10` in your for loop, include the line `print(paste("finished file", i))`.  This will print a running tally to your console window.